# debounce angular 2 with ngModelChange

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I have a `ngModelChange` on a `textArea` like this :

```
      <ion-textarea placeholder="Type your message here" formControlName="message" [(ngModel)]="message" (ngModelChange)="changing($event)"></ion-textarea>
```

And now I'd like to know where the user is typing on this `textarea` or not, so I'd like to use debounce with a timmer of 5000 for example to know if he's typing or not, not sending for every letter he's typing, I want to fire this event every 5 seconds, how could I implement it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <input type="text" (keyup)='keyUp.next($event)'>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;

  public keyUp = new Subject<string>();

  constructor() {
    const observable = this.keyUp
      .map(value => event.target.value)
      .debounceTime(1000)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .flatMap((search) => {
        return Observable.of(search).delay(500);
      })
      .subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: what's the difference between ngOnChange and keyUp what's better?

Comment: but how do you implement these for an array of strings where the input is inside *ngFor?

Comment: @anaval can you ellaborate your question

Comment: lets say I have a form with a series of inputs
all inputs are emails because the user can have an array of emails
And I want to use debounce time on them all

Answer (score 5):

Create a `Subject` in your component. In your `changing` method call `next` on the subject. Next subscribe to your subject with a debounce:

```
export class MyComponent {
  mySubject = new Subject();

  contructor(){
    this.mySubject
      .debounceTime(5000)
      .subscribe(val => {
        //do what you want
      });
  }

  changing(event){
    this.mySubject.next(event.valueFromInput);
  }
}
```

Comment: How do I call next? and where?

Comment: What's the difference between your answer and @Rahul answers?

Comment: What's valueFromInput?

Comment: somewhere in your event object is the value from the input

Comment: Property 'debounce' does not exist on type 'Subject<{}>' debounce crashes

Comment: Yes but I'm not using an input amb I'm using textArea

Comment: add `import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounce';` to your imports

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149090/discussion-between-stuart2041-and-robin-dijkhof).